# Why do I get ArgumentError when sorting floats contained within an object in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, sorting, floating-point

I can sort a list of floats, no problem.  But if I'm trying to compare floats in an object to sort objects in a list, I get this error:

```
`sort': comparison of HateRuby with HateRuby failed (ArgumentError)
```

Here's some code:

```
class HateRuby
    attr_reader :aFloat
    attr_writer :aFloat

    def initialize(f)
        @aFloat = f
    end
end

puts "#{RUBY_VERSION}-p#{RUBY_PATCHLEVEL}\n\n"

x = []
x << HateRuby.new(3.3)
x << HateRuby.new(2.2)
x << HateRuby.new(1.1)

puts "x contents:"
x.each { |f| puts "#{'%.2f' % f.aFloat}: #{f.aFloat.class}" }

x.sort { |a,b| a.aFloat <=> b.aFloat }

y = x.sort

puts "y contents:"
y.each { |f| puts "#{'%.2f' % f.aFloat}: #{f.aFloat.class}" }
```

This produces:

```
[path]/Ruby/rb3D54.tmp:21:in `sort': comparison of HateRuby with HateRuby failed (ArgumentError)
    from [path]/Ruby/rb3D54.tmp:21:in `<main>'
1.9.3-p125

x contents:
3.30: Float
2.20: Float
1.10: Float
Complete(1)
```

I don't really hate Ruby, of course, but I am annoyed...

Thanks to anyone listening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`y = x.sort` causing the error, as [`#sort`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort) compares object using the method `<=>`. But you didn't define the method. There is no `HateRuby#<=>` method in your class `HateRuby`.

While you would write `collection_object.sort`, an implicit block has been supplied, like `collection_object.sort { |a,b| a  <=> b }`. This way sorting is being done.

Now see it is working :

```
class HateRuby
    attr_reader :aFloat
    attr_writer :aFloat

    def initialize(f)
        @aFloat = f
    end
    def <=>(ob)
      # just for clarity I use `self`, you can remove it. as it is implicit.
      self.aFloat <=> ob.aFloat 
    end
end

x = []
x << HateRuby.new(3.3)
x << HateRuby.new(2.2)
x << HateRuby.new(1.1)
x.sort
# => [#<HateRuby:0x9e73d2c @aFloat=1.1>,
#     #<HateRuby:0x9e73d40 @aFloat=2.2>,
#     #<HateRuby:0x9e73d54 @aFloat=3.3>]
```

Comment: So, to be clear, this code: `x.sort { |a,b| a.aFloat <=> b.aFloat }` is no good...it doesn't redefine sort to compare the attributes at all?  --Thanks

Comment: @Ratel: it returns a sorted array, which you completely ignore.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement the method `<=>` from the Mixin `Comparable`:

```
include Comparable
```

and

```
def <=> (other)
```

Answer (score 0):

You were very close. The sort method does not sort the array itself, it delivers a sorted copy. You have to assign a variable to it. This is your code with one line changed and one line gone:

```
class HateRuby
    attr_reader :aFloat
    attr_writer :aFloat

    def initialize(f)
        @aFloat = f
    end
end

puts "#{RUBY_VERSION}-p#{RUBY_PATCHLEVEL}\n\n"

x = []
x << HateRuby.new(3.3)
x << HateRuby.new(2.2)
x << HateRuby.new(1.1)

puts "x contents:"
x.each { |f| puts "#{'%.2f' % f.aFloat}: #{f.aFloat.class}" }

y = x.sort { |a,b| a.aFloat <=> b.aFloat } # <== This line changed
# y = x.sort                               # <== This line removed

puts "y contents:"
y.each { |f| puts "#{'%.2f' % f.aFloat}: #{f.aFloat.class}" }
```